# image replacement loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, image

So I'm learning a image replacement technique on W3, and here's what I want:

1. There is an image of a dog.
2. When I click this image, this image will be replaced by a picture of a cat.
3. However, if I click this image again, it will be replaced again by the dog that was
   originally there.
4. And if I click once more, the cat will replace the dog.
5. And so on.

How do I go about making a permanent loop of replacing these two images?

Here's a link that's similar to what I want to do:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_src

In that example if you click the image, it will replace the image once. But if you click on it a second time, the original image won't replace it.

So yeah, any help on making an efficient algorithm that can constantly replace an original with a new image, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<img id="img" src="cat.jpg" />​
```

JavaScript using jQuery,

```
$('#img').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'dog.jpg');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'cat.jpg');
    }
);​
```

Here is the working demo, http://jsfiddle.net/D9VvV/

Answer (score 0):

Put the images in an array, and use a variable to keep track of which image to show next:

```
var images = ["hackanm.gif", "compman.gif"];
var index = 0;

function changeSrc() {
  document.getElementById("myImage").src = images[index];
  index = (index + 1) % images.length;
}
```